# Entity Framework 5 Code Migration doesn't create database

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to use Entity Framework 5 Code First.
I've created model classes and context.

After that following Microsoft instructions I've enabled code migrations.

Than I skipped running my application (during which DB should be created first time) and use Add-Migration command. Migration was generated successfully.

Update-Database call was also successfull. **But I'm not seeing my DB at all.** It is absent!

SQL Management Studio and Visual Studio Server Explorer show only 4 default system databases and that's all!
I also tried to launch my application - it doesn't change anything.
I'm using

```
public MyContext() : base("name=MyContext") { }
```

such type of constructor (so I need specify connection string with **MyContext** name.
Here is my **app.config** example:

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
      <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <entityFramework>
      <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
          <parameter value="v11.0" />
        </parameters>
      </defaultConnectionFactory>
    </entityFramework>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
    <connectionStrings>
      <add name="BettyContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=MyDB.sdf"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I have no idea what's going on. Seems that no one has such problem. May be I've missed some evident thing, but howbeit I'm waiting for some help.

Comment: Do you see an exception? If you don't see an exception you probably are not looking at the right database. You can try adding some data to the database with your app and then read it. If the data can be successfully added and read and you still don't see the database it would confirm that you are looking at wrong database.

Comment: I've written unit test which writes 1 entity to DB and than reads it. It seems everything is OK. I'm feeling stupid now, because I still can't understand where actually is my DB???

Comment: (This might be brute force but it should be relatively fast and easy.) I would just run `dir C:\MyDB.sdf /s` in an elevated command prompt (probably on all your partitions) and it should find all MyDB.sdf files on your computer. Then it should be easy to find out which one is being used. You can also provide an absolute path in your config file (e.g. Data Source=C:\temp\MyDB.sdf) and then you should have no doubts.

Comment: Thanks. I've found it. But location is strange.
It is stored here: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE" and in the Bin directory of unit test project which I used to test write\read from DB.
And also I can't open it neigher through Visual Studio Server Explorer nor SQL Management Studio.
How can I access this DB and why there are two instances?

Comment: I don't know why you have two instances maybe one is created when you run your tests and the other one when you run your app? I think it's recommended to use an absolute path for data source and this way you can avoid the confusion. You may not have permissions to access this database - try running Sql Server Management Studio as administrator to see if this is the case.

Comment: Oh, it's smth confusing in Microsoft docs about EF5. They use *.sdf files in connection string "Data Source=MyDB.sdf" and say that this is LocalDB, but seems it is SQL Server CE. I'm edited my connection string to "Server=(LocalDB)\v11.0; Integrated Security=true ;AttachDbFileName=E:\MyDB.mdf" and database was created successfully, I can see it and it apears in SQL Management Studio automatically.

Comment: By the way, if you know EF 5 well, can you help me with one more question:

Is "dbo.__MigrationHistory" a place where is stored current DB migration status? Or its just a history (log)?
And if I want to create a DB with migrations from the same Code First model at another PC I can start from calling Update-Database? command or I have to do everything from beginning (Enable-Migration, Add-Migration, Update-Database) or I have to do everything except Add-Migration (it is already present and it seems strange to add it once again for every new developer for example)?

Comment: Before you did not have Server specified. As for the other question I would recommend starting a new thread.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Here is new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12834558/entity-framework-5-code-migrations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see an exception? If you don't see an exception you probably are not looking at the right database. You can try adding some data to the database with your app and then read it. If the data can be successfully added and read and you still don't see the database it would confirm that you are looking at wrong database.

Comment: That is the first think I also thought but do you mean looking at wrong database or server?

Comment: Either. If you have a connection string that points to a different server and you *think* your app is using it while it actually cannot find the connection string and uses the default setting (which will be a local sqlexpress or localdb) then it is a different server. If you have both localdb and SqlExpress installed on your box than you may be looking at localdb while the app is using SqlExpress so you have the same machine but different databases. If you rename the namespace your DbContext lives and don't use specific database name CodeFirst will create a new db and you may be looking at old